# How kubernetes block, file and object storage types are used inside containers

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, object-storage, file-storage, block-storage

In the context of Kubernetes, I've come across the terms `Block Storage`, `File Storage` and `Object Storage` but I don't understand how they are really used (mounted) inside a container. I have a few questions,

1. Are these all storage types backed by raw block devices?
2. Is `Block Storage` a term used to mean a **logical abstraction of block devices**?
3. Is `Block Storage` mounted to a path inside a container just like we mount a file system on linux? which also implies the question whether the `Block Storage` is a formatted file system?
4. How `Object Storage` is presented to a container? How does the container make use of it? Is it mounted to a path?
5. How `File Storage` is presented to a container? How does the container make use of it? Is it mounted to a path?
6. What are 3 example scenarios to use these 3 storage types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Block storage** is backed by block device. It can be physical disk or it can be network-attached device (iSCSI, FC or AWS EBS volume) or even Ceph RBD. In most cases pods don't need to work with raw block devices (with exception of Kube native storages like Ceph, Portworx) and Kubernetes instead creates filesystem on top of it and mounts it into pod. The main thing about block storage is that in most cases it's Read-Write Only (RWO) which means it can be mounted read-write only to single pod.

**File storage** is backed by filesystem. It can be local filesystem, like hostPath, or it can be network share like NFS. In that case Kubernetes can directly mount it inside pod without any additional preparation. The main thing about NFS is that it can be mounted Read-Write Many (RWX) which means it can be mounted read-write to many pods. Also filesystems on one node can be attached to many pods on that particular node.

**Object storage** can be imagined like files-over-HTTP(S) (AWS S3, GCP GCS, Azure Blob Storage, Ceph RGW, Minio). There is no official Kubernetes supported way to mount object storage inside pods, but there are some dirty workarounds like s3fs, Ganesha NFS and may be others. In most cases you will work with object storage directly from your app using provider specific libraries which is how it's meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

**File Storage**: Applications requiring shared file systems and shared data across multiple instances. For example, consider where multiple instances of a web server need access to the same set of media files, documents, or other shared resources, File storage is well-suited for this scenario, as it provides a centralized location for storing and accessing files.
***Scenario***: A WordPress deployment in Kubernetes might use a file storage solution for the persistent volume that holds media uploads, ensuring that all WordPress pods can access and modify the same set of media files.
***ReadWriteMany***: The PVC can be mounted by multiple pods. All pods have read-only access.

**Block Storage**: It is a storage option that breaks data into "blocks" and stores those blocks across which is faster to store and retrieve than large data objects. Thus application a database system that needs high-performance storage with direct access to raw storage devices. Block storage is suitable for databases that need low-latency and high-throughput access to data.
***Scenario***: An application using a stateful database like MySQL or MariaDB. Each database pod would have its own dedicated block storage, allowing for efficient and direct access to the underlying storage device.
***ReadWriteOnce***: The PVC can be mounted by one pod only. This pod can read from and write to the volume.

**Objects Storage**: this include data, a globally unique identifier and metadata for indexing and management. It is often used for handling large amounts of unstructured data.
***Scenario***:  Efficiently manage logs and metrics for monitoring purposes or archiving the historical data.
***AccessMode*** can be ReadWriteOnce or ReadWritemany.